# Render different errors for different pipelines (:api and :browser)?

Tags: api, http, elixir, phoenix-framework

In my current Phoenix project I have both a `:browser` pipeline and a `:api` pipeline. I want to render different error messages for each pipeline. However, I'm not sure how to achieve it.

My `router.ex` is like:

```
  scope "/api", AppWeb do
    pipe_through(:api)
    # ...
  end

  scope "/admin", AppWeb do
    pipe_through :browser
    # ...
  end
```

I want all requests to non-existing routes under `/admin` to render a HTTP error template, but all requests to any other route to render a JSON error template.

In `config.exs` I have

`render_errors: [view: AppWeb.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(json html)]`

However, I'm not sure how to proceed with the error view.

It seems that the `template_not_found/2` function will be automatically called, whenever a routing error occurs, however, this function doesn't have a `conn` argument. Its arguments are `template` and `assigns`.

Should I try to inspect the `assigns` to try to determine which route the incoming request was trying to access? Trying to inspect the template didn't seem to be helpful, and the template attempted to be rendered all seem to end with `.html` extension, even if I try to visit a route under `/api`.

Comment: Are you accessing it from the browser? The browser gives the HTML content-type higher priority and therefore, once we have to negotiate which format to use, we will pick it up. However, if you do a request with `curl` and set `Accept: application/json` header, like an API client would, then you should get JSON back.

Comment: @JoséValim Thanks. Setting the header worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JoséValim pointed out, the reason why I didn't correctly see JSON error messages is because I was visiting the pages via a browser. If I correctly set the header `Accept: application/json` in my request, it worked.

In `template_not_found` function in `error_view.ex`, it seems to suffice to just write       `Phoenix.Controller.status_message_from_template(template)`.